# Track time in state variables in data tables in R

Tags: r, data.table, time-series, data-manipulation

Imagine a `data.table` in `R` given by

```
library(data.table)
dtable = data.table(
  id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 2)),
  time = c(seq(1, 3, 1), seq(1, 4, 1), seq(3, 4)),
  state_1 = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A'),
  state_2 = c('A', 'B', 'A', NA, 'B', 'B', NA, 'A', 'A')
)
```

which evaluates to

```
   id time state_1 state_2
1:  1    1       A       A
2:  1    2       A       B
3:  1    3       B       A
4:  2    1       A    <NA>
5:  2    2       B       B
6:  2    3       B       B
7:  2    4       B    <NA>
8:  3    3       A       A
9:  3    4       A       A
```

I wish to track how long time each state in each row have been in the current state. I wish to consider my data both left-censored and not. I.e. one solution should always return `NA` for the first observations of each `id` until changes in states are observed. The other solution should treat the first observation like the state has just changed to that state. My resulting `data.table` should return

```
   id time state_1 state_2 time_in_state_1_censored time_in_state_2_censored time_in_state_1 time_in_state_2
1:  1    1       A       A                 NA                 NA               0               0
2:  1    2       A       B                 NA                  0               1               0
3:  1    3       B       A                  0                  0               0               0
4:  2    1       A    <NA>                 NA                 NA               0               0
5:  2    2       B       B                  0                  0               0               0
6:  2    3       B       B                  1                  1               1               1
7:  2    4       B    <NA>                  2                  0               2               0
8:  3    3       A       A                 NA                 NA               0               0
9:  3    4       A       A                 NA                 NA               1               1
```

I've partly solved the non-censoring part by using `rle` (on `id < 3`)

```
dtable[id < 3, 
       (paste0('time_in_', columns)) := 
         lapply(.SD, function(col) unlist(sapply(rle(col)$lengths, function(x) 1:x-1))), 
       by='id', .SDcols = columns]
```

But I am sure it can be solved smarter, more robust and more efficient probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uncensored one is

```
dtable[, v := rowid(rleid(state_1)) - 1L, by = id]
```

From there, to get the censored one, I would ...

```
# label spells in each state
dtable[, spell_num := rleid(state_1), by=id]

# overwrite with NA for the first spell
dtable[, vc := v][spell_num == 1L, vc := NA]
```

To do this for multiple state columns, I'd use a loop:

```
for (s in sprintf("state_%s", 1:2)){
  sid = sub(".*_(.*)$", "\\1", s)
  outnm_un = sprintf("v_%s", sid)
  outnm_cs = sprintf("vc_%s", sid)

  # label spells in each state
  dtable[, spell_num := rleidv(.SD), by=id, .SDcols = s]

  # create uncensored var
  dtable[, (outnm_un) := rowid(spell_num) - 1L, by=id]

  # overwrite with NA for the first spell to get the censored var
  dtable[, (outnm_cs) := get(outnm_un)][spell_num == 1L, (outnm_cs) := NA]

}

# clean up
dtable[, spell_num := NULL]
rm(s, sid, outnm_un, outnm_cs)
```

which gives

```
   id time state_1 state_2 v vc v_1 vc_1 v_2 vc_2
1:  1    1       A       A 0 NA   0   NA   0   NA
2:  1    2       A       B 1 NA   1   NA   0    0
3:  1    3       B       A 0  0   0    0   0    0
4:  2    1       A      NA 0 NA   0   NA   0   NA
5:  2    2       B       B 0  0   0    0   0    0
6:  2    3       B       B 1  1   1    1   1    1
7:  2    4       B      NA 2  2   2    2   0    0
8:  3    3       A       A 0 NA   0   NA   0   NA
9:  3    4       A       A 1 NA   1   NA   1   NA
```

**Simplification edit**

Following the solution above it can be compressed into

```
columns = c('state_1', 'state_2')
censor = TRUE

dtable[, (paste0('time_in_', columns)) := lapply(.SD, function(sd_col){
  spell_num = rleid(sd_col)
  v = rowid(spell_num) - 1
  if (isTRUE(censor)) v[spell_num == 1] <- NA
  v
}), by=id, .SDcols = columns]
```

Comment: Very nice. I've submitted a proposal for an edit to simplify your solution exploting `data.table`, `lapply` and `.SD`.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by the following

```
dtable[, 
       (paste0('time_in_', columns, '_censored')) := 
         lapply(.SD, function(col) {
           rles = rle(col)
           res = rep(NA, rles$lengths[1])
           if (length(rles$lengths) > 1){
             res = c(res, unlist(sapply(rle(col)$lengths[-1], function(x) 1:x-1)))
           }
           return(as.integer(res))
         }), 
       by='id', .SDcols = columns]
dtable[, 
       (paste0('time_in_', columns)) := 
         lapply(.SD, function(col) {
           rles = rle(col)
           if (length(rles$lengths) > 1){
             res = unlist(sapply(rle(col)$lengths, function(x) 1:x-1))
           } else {
             res = 0:(rles$lengths[1]-1)
           }
           return(as.integer(res))
         }), 
       by='id', .SDcols = columns]
```

which evaluates to

```
   id time state_1 state_2 time_in_state_1_censored time_in_state_2_censored time_in_state_1 time_in_state_2
1:  1    1       A       A                       NA                       NA               0               0
2:  1    2       A       B                       NA                        0               1               0
3:  1    3       B       A                        0                        0               0               0
4:  2    1       A    <NA>                       NA                       NA               0               0
5:  2    2       B       B                        0                        0               0               0
6:  2    3       B       B                        1                        1               1               1
7:  2    4       B    <NA>                        2                        0               2               0
8:  3    3       A       A                       NA                       NA               0               0
9:  3    4       A       A                       NA                       NA               1               1
```